# Vim Triple Braces Code Folding in Emacs?

Tags: code-folding, vim-emulation

I am migrating from Vim to Emacs because I can't get Org mode to work in Vim. In Emacs is there a way to replicate Vim's marker folding so that

```
# Foo {{{  
foo  
# }}}
```

Turns into

```
+--  1 lines: # Foo ----
```

via *foldmethod=marker* and *foldlevel=0*. I have tried using vimish-fold and origami with no success. I am running Emacs GTK2 on FreeBSD 11.1 with the Evil mode plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Folding mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode) (`folding.el`) to achieve what you want. The Emacs wiki page, and the `.el` file have extensive documentation, but in short this is what I do to get equivalent folding in both `vim` and `emacs`.

After installing `folding.el`, in add the following to your `~/.emacs`:

```
(autoload 'folding-mode          "folding" "Folding mode" t)
(autoload 'turn-off-folding-mode "folding" "Folding mode" t)
(autoload 'turn-on-folding-mode  "folding" "Folding mode" t)
```

Then in the files you want to enable folding, use [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) to enable folding. For `emacs` and `vim` I add at the beginning of the file:

```
;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; mode: folding; folded-file: t; -*-
;; vim: syntax=lisp: foldmethod=marker
```

The `emacs` variables enable folding mode, and sets a file to folded when you open it.

To fold a block of code/text in a file you mark it with 'comment-symbol-and-three-braces". In the case of elisp this would look like:

```
;;{{{ folding mode

(autoload 'folding-mode          "folding" "Folding mode" t)
(autoload 'turn-off-folding-mode "folding" "Folding mode" t)
(autoload 'turn-on-folding-mode  "folding" "Folding mode" t)

;;}}}
```

Folded this renders like:

```
;;{{{ folding mode...
```

And in `vim` renders as:

```
+--- 13 lines: folding mode---------
```

**Note:** in the mark constitutes the comment symbol and three braces (without a space in between). It is not just the three braces. Also, the comment comes after the mark.

There are other ways to fold files such as [Hide Show](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) and [Outline mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode), but this is how I get folding done for the same file in both `vim` and `emacs`.